# ¿Para que sirve el operador '>>' en Java?

Tags: java, operador

Tengo un problema con el uso de el carácter **'>>'** quisiera saber que función cumple en realidad que es lo que hace teniendo en cuenta algo como :

`System.out.println(5>>1);` el resultado es **2** pero por que?, entiendo que es llamado también operador de **Bits** pero realmente compara los bits de estos números y determina que?

Comment: Para entender mejor revisa el tema de operadores de bit entre los cuales se encuentra el operador >> que es el operador de deplazamiento de bits a la derecha.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para saber el porqué, tienes que pasar el numero 5 a binario: `00000101`

El operador `>>` desplaza `X bits` hacia la derecha dependiendo del número que hay después del operador, en tu caso `1 bit`, por lo tanto `00000101 -> 00000010` que es `2`

Comment: Gracias Marc me quedo muy claro te lo agradezco amigo.